# Uninitialized Constant Error from Ruby EventMachine Chat Server

Tags: ruby, events, chat

I'm trying to build a chat server in ruby using EventManager. Needless to day, I'm new to Ruby and feeling a little over my head with the current error I am getting, as I have no clue what it means and a search doesn't return anything valuable. Here's some of the logistics-

(ive only implemented LOGIN and REGISTER so I'll only include those..) 
user can enter-
REGISTER username password - registers user
LOGIN username password    - logins user

I'm taking in the string of data the user sends, splitting it into an array called msg, and then acting on the data based on msg[0] (as its the command, like REGISTER, LOGIN, etc)

Here is my code, all contained in a single file- chatserver.rb (explanation follows):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'eventmachine'

class Server
  attr_accessor :clients, :channels, :userCreds, :userChannels

  def initialize
    @clients     = [] #list of clients connected e.g. [192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3]
    @users       = {} #list of users 'logged in' e.g. [tom, sam, jerry]
    @channels    = [] #list of channels          e.g. [a, b, c]
    @userCreds   = {} #user credentials hash     e.g. { tom: password1, sam: password2, etc }
    @userChanels = {} #users and their channels  e.g. { tom: a, sam: a, jerry: b }
  end

  def start
    @signature = EventMachine.start_server("127.0.0.1", 3200, Client) do |con|
      con.server = self
    end
  end

  def stop
    EventMachine.stop_server(@signature)

    unless wait_for_connections_and_stop
      EventMachine.add_periodic.timer(1) { wait_for_connections_and_stop }
    end
  end

  # Does the username already exist?  
  def has_username?(name)
    @userCreds.has_key?(name)
  end

  # Is the user already logged in?
  def logged_in?(name)
    if @users[name] == 1
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

  # Did the user enter the correct pwd?
  def correct_pass?(pass)
    if @userCreds[name] == pass
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

  private

    def wait_for_connections_and_stop
      if @clients.empty?
        EventMachine.stop
        true
      else
        puts "Waiting for #{@clients.size} client(s) to stop"
        false
      end
    end
end

class Connection < EventMachine::Connection
  attr_accessor :server, :name, :msg

  def initialize
    @name = nil
    @msg = []
  end

  # First thing the user sees when they connect to the server.
  def post_init
    send_data("Welcome to the lobby.\nRegister or Login with REGISTER/LOGIN username password\nOr try HELP if you get stuck!")
  end

  # Start parsing incoming data
  def receive_data(data)
    data.strip!
    msg = data.split("") #split data by spaces and throw it in array msg[]
    if data.empty? #the user entered nothing?
      send_data("You didn't type anything! Try HELP.")
      return
    elsif msg[0] == "REGISTER"
      handle_register(msg) #send msg to handle_register method
    else
      hanlde_login(msg)    #send msg to handle_login method
    end
  end

  def unbind
    @server.clients.each { |client| client.send_data("#{@name} has just left") }
    puts("#{@name} has just left") 
    @server.clients.delete(self)
  end

  private

    def handle_register(msg)
      if @server.has_username? msg[1] #user trying to register with a name that already exists?
        send_data("That username is already taken! Choose another or login.")
        return
      else
        @name = msg[1] #set name to username
        @userCreds[name] = msg[2] #add username and password to user credentials hash
        send_data("OK")  #send user OK message
      end
    end

end

EventMachine::run do
  s = Server.new
  s.start  #start server
  puts "Server listening"
end
```

Whew, okay, it's only the beginning, so not that complicated. Since I'm new to Ruby I have a feeling I'm just not declaring variable or using scope correctly. Here's the error output:

> chatserver.rb:16:in `start': uninitialized constant Server::Client
>   (NameError)   from chatserver.rb:110:in`block in '     from
>   /Users/meth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in
>   `call'    from
>   /Users/meth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in`
>   run_machine'     from
>   /Users/meth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in
>   `run'     from chatserver.rb:108:in`<\main>'

ignore the slash in main in that last line.
line 108 is the last function- EventMachine::run do etc.

Any help would be appreciated, if I didn't provide enough info just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that when you call `EventMachine::start_server` you need to give it your `Connection` class as the handler. `Client` is not defined anywhere.